# Is there a word for using a shell as a refuge?

Tags: word-request

Some animals use shells as a sort of refuge to protect themselves. Is there a particular verb for it? I am not sure if I ever heard of such a word, but there must be a word for it or at least a better way to say it than "take refuge in a shell", because it's too long-winded.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **hide** and still convey the same meaning.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hide):

> to conceal for shelter or protection. E.g. 
>   *They hid him from the police.*

So in your case, it would be ***Some animals hide in their shell***

Answer (score 1):

**Retreat** is a possible option: *Some animals **retreat** into their shells when in danger*

> an act or process of withdrawing especially from what is difficult, dangerous, or disagreeable
>
> -- [M-W meaning 1.a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retreat)